# How to format time with seconds properly on Android?

Tags: java, android, time, formatting, locale

I cannot find a way to properly format time with seconds, without manually specifying formatting mask.

What I've tried:

- java.text.DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG) - results in something like "10:15:18 PM EST", even though I have 24-hour display enabled in settings, (and various other software honors it)
- android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat() - results in "22:15" - correct 24-hour, but no seconds.

Is there any other way I missed?

Maybe I should stick with SimpleDateFormat, manually specifying fromat string depending on android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat()? Should work, but still a bit of a hack...

Comment: what is the problem with specefying the formatting mask ?

Comment: I am in no way sure that all locales use ":" as separator, for example.